# Passing arguments to Url.Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

What is the difference between these two ways of passing arguments to an Action?

```
(1) @Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")?arg1=5&arg2="hello";
(2) @Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new {arg1=5, arg2="hello"});
```

Comment: The first one you haven't actually passed any arguments to `Url.Action`, you're just concatenating two strings

Answer (score 1):

The difference is whether you're taking ASP.Net **Routing** into account.

Assuming you have a route defined as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CallMyAction",
        url: "CallMyAction/{arg1}-{arg2}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" });
```

Your 1st call would generate the following URL:

```
/CallMyAction?arg1=5&arg2=hello
```

While the 2nd call would generate a URL that is adhering the route pattern you defined:

```
/CallMyAction/5-hello
```